# Packing/Unpacking C-Style Arrays with Msgpack

Tags: msgpack

I have downloaded 1.4.1 and searched all the examples, Wiki and on Google as well but couldn't find anything, so turning here.

Is there any way that I can pack/unpack arrays having data type of char, std::string, user defined class?

```
char data[10];
std::string data2[10];
UserClass data3[20];
```

I have tried doing it for std::string array but couldn't make it work.

I am porting my code from boost::serialization library to MsgPack. I will appreciate any help.

Thanks & Regards,
Owais.

Comment: I posted the pull request to msgpack-c to support C-Style array. See https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/issues/465

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, msgpack-c version 1.4.1 doesn't have a functionality that pack/unpack C-Style array. The only exception is the C-Style array of char. It is packed as STR (https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#formats-str).

Maybe it is not the behavior you expected.

msgpack-c version 2.0 will support pack/unpack C-Style array. It have already been supported on `master` branch. See  https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/pull/466

It can pack/unpack all of the following variables:

```
char data[10];
std::string data2[10];
UserClass data3[20];
```

See a working complete example:
http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/20WTgAATDhTX3rBA

An array of std::string and an array of UserClass can be passed to `msgpack::pack` and `msgpack::object::convert`. It's simple.

```
// Packing
std::stringstream ss;
std::string data2[2] = { "ABC", "DEFG" };
msgpack::pack(ss, data2); // As ARRAY

// Unpacking
auto oh2 = msgpack::unpack(ss.str().data(), ss.str().size(), off);

// Converting
std::string c_data2[2];
oh2.get().convert(c_data2);
```

But an array of char is packed as STR as the default. If you want to pack it as ARRAY, then you need to use `msgpack::type::array_ref`. For convenience, `msgpack::type::make_array_ref` function is provided to create `msgpack::type::array_ref`.

```
std::stringstream ss;
char data1[3] = { 'A', 'B', '\0' };

// Packing
msgpack::pack(ss, msgpack::type::make_array_ref(data1)); // As ARRAY

// Unpacking
auto oh1_array = msgpack::unpack(ss.str().data(), ss.str().size(), off);

// Converting
char c_data1_array[3];
auto ar = msgpack::type::make_array_ref(c_data1_array);
oh1_array.get().convert(ar);
```

Here is mapping between C-Stype array and msgpack types.

```
char[]          : STR
unsigned char[] : BIN
T[]             : ARRAY (T means all other types.)
```

So when you want to map `char[]` and `unsigned char[]` to ARRAY, you need to use `msgpack::type::array_ref`.

Comment: Would this work for a variable/dynamic length array, even if the size is known?

Comment: What does dynamic length array mean? On C++?